# Graphql Yoga Playground with Lambda - "Server cannot be reached"

Tags: javascript, node.js, aws-lambda, graphql

I'm in the process of setting a graphql endpoint with servlerless/ lambda and am receiving an error when trying to connect to the graphql playground that comes with graphql-yoga. When I go to my route that has the playground (`/playground`) it launches the playground interface however it just says:

> Server cannot be reached

In the top right of the playground. It's worth noting i'm using the `makeRemoteExecutableSchema` utility to proxy to another graphql endpoint (which is my CMS called Prismic). I don't believe this is the issue as I have successfully connected to it with the playground when testing on a normal express server.

Here is the code in my **handler.js**

```
'use strict';

const { makeRemoteExecutableSchema } = require('graphql-tools');
const { PrismicLink } = require("apollo-link-prismic");
const { introspectSchema } = require('graphql-tools');
const { ACCESS_TOKEN, CMS_URL } = process.env;
const { GraphQLServerLambda } = require('graphql-yoga')

const lambda = async () => {
  const link = PrismicLink({
    uri: CMS_URL,
    accessToken: ACCESS_TOKEN
  });

  const schema = await introspectSchema(link);

  const executableSchema = makeRemoteExecutableSchema({
    schema,
    link,
  });

  return new GraphQLServerLambda({ 
    schema: executableSchema,
    context: req => ({ ...req })
  });
}

exports.playground = async (event, context, callback) => {
  context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop = false;
  const graphQl = await lambda();
  return graphQl.playgroundHandler(event, context, callback);
};
```

I have followed [this](https://itnext.io/building-a-graphql-api-using-graphql-yoga-lambda-and-mongodb-c0c195621f47) guide for getting it running up till here and am fairly sure i've followed similar steps for what applies to what i'm trying to do but can't seem to figure out where i've gone wrong.

Thanks,

Comment: You should check the network tab in Chrome Dev Tools to see the HTTP request it fires to your graphql endpoint. Hopefully, it will tell you more about the error and if you post it here, someone might be able to help.

Comment: The tutorial you are using does not talk about permissions. Have you configured permissions for you lambda to allow network requests?

Answer (score 0):

Could you take a look at what version of the graphql-yoga package you are using?

I had a similar problem using the Apollo server in combination with Kentico Cloud Headless CMS and I found this issue:

- https://github.com/prisma/graphql-yoga/issues/267

Comment: I have also faced some problems that **on the production environment is playground turned off by default** and you need to programmatically turn it on when creating the endpoint. And also allow introspection to allow playground to load the schema definition.